# Let $X$ have a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ have a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$.

(a) Show that the moment-generating function of $$Y = \frac{X − \lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$$ is given by
$$M_Y(t)=\exp(\lambda e^{\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}}}-\sqrt{\lambda}t-\lambda)$$

(b) $X$, the number of accidents per year at a given intersection, is assumed to have a Poisson distribution. Over the past few years, an average of 36 accidents per year have occurred at this intersection. If the number of accidents per year is at least 45, an intersection can qualify to be redesigned under an emergency program set up by the state. Approximate the probability that this intersection will come under the emergency program at the end of the next year.

**Attempt**

Part (a) is fairly straightforward as is basically just an exercise in algebra. However, whenever I need to actually deal with numbers in probability I get all confused. So, can someone help me with part (b)

What I have so far is this: it makes sense to use the result fond in part (a) Then it is given that $\lambda=36$ and $t=1$. So can I just substitute this value into the moment generating function for part (a) and solve? i.e.

\begin{align}
\exp(\lambda e^{\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}}}-\sqrt{\lambda}t-\lambda)&=\exp(36 e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{36}}}-\sqrt{36}\cdot 1-36)\\
&=\exp(36 e^{\frac{1}{6}}-6-36)\\
&=\exp(36(1.1813604)-42)\\
&=\exp(42.52897487-42)\\
&=\exp(0.52897487)\\
&=1.697
\end{align}
But does this give a probability greater than 1? I have expected a smaller number. Moreover, I do not use the number 45 any were in this calculation which leads me to suspect I have completely missed something here.

Comment: (a) and (b) are not really connected.

Comment: Ok, am I meant to use Markov's inequality or Chebyshev's inequality for part (b)?

Comment: In the old days I would have used the method in heropups's answer. Nowadays software will compute $\Pr(X\le 44)$ quickly.

Comment: Why part (a) was included in this posting is unclear.

Answer (score 3):

Use a normal approximation with continuity correction.  This is possible because $\lambda = 36$ is quite large, so that $$X \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda = 36) \approx \operatorname{Normal}(\mu = 36, \sigma = 6).$$  Then the desired probability is $$\Pr[X \ge 45] \approx \Pr\left[\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} \ge \frac{45 - 36 - 0.5}{6}\right] = \Pr[Z \ge 1.41667],$$ where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable.

Comment: Oh geez. That seems quit obvious now that I see it. Thank you!